# Excel Creating New Sheet with Summed Data from related sheet

Tags: excel, summarization, vba

Lets say I have the following on a sheet.

[image]

By some means, I want to either replace this, or preferably, create a new sheet, with the following data.  Notice, that PO# is out of the picture, and a summation is done on rest of the fields.  Is there a way to easily do this?

The end result has to be data in excel grid like below (preferably on a new sheet).  This can possibly be some macro or some other technique I can use to easily create this....[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Do you need VBA, what about just `SUMIFS()`?

Comment: You could use a pivot table and just refresh when your data changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with `SUMIFS()` or a **Pivot Table**.

For SUMIFS() the below equation will give you the sum for W.PS123 Product A. Modify as needed for your other criteria by swapping AR and product number (both housed in quotes in below formula, you can also set these equal to a cell range that contains desired criteria).

If you have a set number of "ARs" and Product Numbers, you will only need to build this table once and the equations will automatically update as your raw data changes.

> =SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"W.PS123",E:E,"A")

*Alternatively*, you can build a pivot table and just refresh this every time your data updates (or create a worksheet_change macro to refresh the table automatically when your data changes).

To build your pivot:

1. Highlight your table array (In your example, Col A-D)
2. Insert > Pivot Table
3. Drag AR to Rows
4. Drag PRODUCT to Rows (Below AR)
5. Drag QTY to "Values" and change the field to "Sum" rather the default count
6. Format to taste